# How to update route without re-rendering page (opening / closing a modal that has its own route)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

In my routes I have set-up a slug for a particular route like so:

```
Main route: /members
Sub route: /members/:slug
```

Now when I go to `www.website.com/members/some-slug`

I will try to detect whether there's a slug or not with:

```
if (this.props.match.params.slug) {
   // If have slug, open a modal window with data that corresponds to that slug
   this.showModal(this.props.match.params.slug);
}
```

What's happening is that showModal will change the state of a Modal component to true (thus reveal it) and also trigger an API call to get the details pertaining to the slug parameter that's passed (e.g. the slug `sarah-smith` is used for a GET request as a param to get Sarah Smith's details).

So all of these are fine so far. However, the issue is the re-rendering of the page when I either:

1. Open the modal
2. Close the modal

We have transitions for each element on the page so if you visit a route, the elements will have a subtle fade-in transition.

When a modal is clicked what I do is (`member.name` being the slug):

```
<Link
    to={`/member/${member.name}`}
</Link>
```

Which causes a re-routing hence you can see those small transitions in the background while the modal is fading into view (as if I am opening `/member/slug` for the first time).

Same with the modal close button, if I click on it, what I do is invoke:

```
closeModal() {
    this.props.history.push("/member");
}
```

Which re-renders the entire page `/member` page and not just close the modal. I can't just use `this.setState({ showModal: false });` since that wouldn't change the route back to `/member`.

Is there a way to resolve this? Or another way of doing it so that the page doesn't re-render while changing the URL?

Comment: Could you reproduce this in sanbox.io or codepen.io?

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your modal in route like this.

Modal

Then this.props.history.push("/path");

Answer (score 0):

I think React-Router docs already have such examples. You can check following

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/modal-gallery.

There is `npm` module available as well https://github.com/davidmfoley/react-router-modal